# Java 12 JMeter 5 HTTP/2 request java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/client/ALPNClientConnectionFactory

Tags: jmeter, http2, jmeter-5.0, java-12, alpn

I am using Java 12, JMeter 5.1.1 on Ubuntu 9.0.4 and bumps into the following exception when trying to send HTTP/2 request:

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
```

And this stack trace in the response body:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:138)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.connect(HTTP2Connection.java:68)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.setConnection(HTTP2Request.java:278)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:138)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:115)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
    at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client.lambda$doStart$1(HTTP2Client.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(HTTP2Client.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1500(ManagedSelector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    ... 1 more
```

JMeter 5.1.1 comes with `jetty-alpn-client-9.4.9.v20180320.jar` by default.

I then download the jetty alpn java client library from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-alpn-java-client/ and put that into jmeter installed lib/ folder and results in this exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/client/ALPNClientConnectionFactory
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:138)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.connect(HTTP2Connection.java:68)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.setConnection(HTTP2Request.java:278)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:138)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:115)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/client/ALPNClientConnectionFactory
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client.lambda$doStart$1(HTTP2Client.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(HTTP2Client.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1500(ManagedSelector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 8 more
```

I switched to Java 11 but get the same error.
Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Download http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-alpn-java-client/ and put in the installed jmeter lib/ folder. JMeter only comes installed with `jetty-alpn-client` which is not enough.

Comment: Can we not just add it to the dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

`No Client ALPNProcessors!` is a message from the Jetty libraries that handle ALPN.

Because you are running in JDK 12 (and I don't think there is any big difference with JDK 11, so JDK 12 should be fine), you must have the `jetty-alpn-java-client` jar in the classpath, so that the Jetty libraries will find an implementation of the `ALPNProcessor.Client` class (via the `ServiceLoader` mechanism) that, as the error shows, cannot be found.

You don't detail how you are setting up TLS, etc. and I would have expected JMeter to have the `jetty-alpn-java-client` jar in the classpath already, but evidently there is something wrong in your setup (or in JMeter's).

I would double check how JMeter configures TLS; if it is using the standard JDK implementation, then it must have the `jetty-alpn-java-client` jar in the classpath.

If JMeter is using other TLS implementations (e.g. Conscrypt), then the Jetty project provides similar libraries (e.g. `jetty-alpn-conscrypt-client` jar) that similarly should be in the classpath.

Comment: I have `jetty-alpn-client-9.4.9.v20180320.jar` and `jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client-9.4.9.v20180320.jar` in lib folder of where JMeter-5.1.1 is installed. What do I miss?

Comment: I don't do any setup for TLS.

Comment: JMeter is missing `jetty-alpn-java-client-9.4.9.v20180320.jar` in the `lib` folder. Just add that (you can download it from http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-alpn-java-client/9.4.9.v20180320/). Let know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter 5 doesn't **officially** support Java 12](https://flood.io/blog/jmeter-5-0-whats-in-the-latest-release/)

> JMeter 5.0 officially requires Java 8 or 9, although later versions may be unofficially compatible. From our internal testing, JMeter will run on Java 11

Also in [JMeter group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/F0SmECtvz3I) announcement:

> JMeter 5.0 is tested on Java 8 to 10, Java 11 should also work.

Notice also Java 12 isn't [Long-Term-Support release](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html)

> Java SE 11 however is an LTS release, and therefore Oracle Customers will receive Oracle Premier Support and periodic update releases, even though Java SE 12 was released

Comment: I switched to Java 11 and get the same error. So it is not about Java version.