# No Client ALPNProcessors JMeter HTTP2 Error even after installing jetty-alpn-java-client or jetty-alpn-conscrypt-client jar

Tags: jmeter, http2

I'm hitting the same Error mentioned in this post with Java 8, JMeter 5.1.1 Version: [Java 12 JMeter 5 HTTP/2 request java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/client/ALPNClientConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605428/java-12-jmeter-5-http-2-request-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-eclipse-jett)

I downloaded the jetty-alpn-java-client from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-alpn-java-client/9.4.9.v20180320/) and installed in lib directory and restarted jmeter, I still see the same issue.
There is no TLS Configuration involved but still I downloaded jetty-alpn-conscrypt-client and installed from this [link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-alpn-conscrypt-client/9.4.9.v20180320/), Still seeing the same issue.

I don't have any code written, I Installed HTTP2 Sampler from JMeter Plugin Manager. Please let me know what am I missing.

Error Code:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:138)
>       at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.connect(HTTP2Connection.java:68)
>       at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.setConnection(HTTP2Request.java:278)
>       at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:138)
>       at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:115)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:57)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client.lambda$doStart$1(HTTP2Client.java:155)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(HTTP2Client.java:438)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:222)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1500(ManagedSelector.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:825)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
>       ... 1 more
>       Suppressed: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/java/client/JDK9ClientALPNProcessor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:65)
>           ... 8 more
>       Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.java.client.OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.init(OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.java:42)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:77)
>           ... 8 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 10 more

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong `alpn-boot` library, you're trying to use `9.4.9.v20180320` which requires Java 9 and you're using Java 8.

there is a table at the bottom of this page: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/alpn-chapter.html

where you can match the relevant version of the `alpn-boot` library with your Java 8 version.

Moreover, you should not be placing the .jar to JMeter's "lib" folder, you should set the relevant `-Xbootclasspath/p:/path/to/alpn-boot.jar` JVM property.

More information:

- [HTTP2 Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin)
- [The New HTTP/2 Plugin for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-http2-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I actually followed this link: https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin which helped to fix this issue but resulted another exception mentioned below:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1771)    
As a result of this exception, I took PCAP and found that JMeter complains Parser Error on GET Response. Attached is the PCAP and Private Key for Debugging.
Note: The Client IP is 10.120.195.6 and Server IP is 10.120.195.63. Let me know if you need any other info on the same.

Comment: Since I am not able to attach the TCPDump here, I was actually seeing Parser Error in TCPDump. Not Sure why HTTP2 GET Response JMeter is not able to Parse Correctly

Comment: Any Inputs or Suggestion or Workaround for the mentioned Parsing Error Issue as I am stuck with this Issue and not able to continue with my Testing using Jmeter.

Srikanth